# How to use both hotkeys AND command tab to go to app window

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, window-manager

I've used both iTerm and the new Warp terminal apps which both offer a hotkey shortcut to open a window. But the hotkey feature disables the native macos command+tab switcher for those apps. I want *both* to work so that either via command+tab OR the hotkey, my currently open terminal window shows. I've tried to set up an Alfred hotkey but "go to window of specific app" doesn't appear to be an option. Any ideas?

Comment: When you enable the hot key, is `Cmd-Tab` disabled universally or just in the App?

Comment: @Allan it's not technically disabled, it just doesn't bring up the window. I can switch to the terminal app, but the window won't appear unless I use the hot key.

Comment: It seems to be working as expected.  `Cmd-Tab` switches to the *Application* whereas the hot key opens an Application *window*.   If you look at the menu bar in the top, you’ll see that the app switched with `Cmd-Tab`

Comment: @Allan correct, it does switch to the app, but I want the window. Normal use of the tab switcher brings up the window but hot-key enabling breaks that.

Comment: It sounds like the App is breaking it. Did you check with the Devs?